# Serial console shows scrambled output

Tags: linux, serial-port, pfsense

I am trying to connect to an APU1C device which has only a serial port using a Usb-to-Serial cable and the Prolific pl2303 module. I was able to connect to it in the past but now I am struggling with a strange behavior I never saw before. I tried the recommended parameters (115200,8,n,1) with minicom, screen and GtkTerm, but all give the same kind of output which is:
[image: Output]

I use a Debian buster linux (Linux 4.16.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.16.5-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux) as a client and trying to install PfSense using the memstick installer.

I saw that some issues were present on the windows drivers due to a copyright infringement and the connection was impossible as a result; could a similar issue affect Linux's drivers as well ?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Output of dmesg | grep tty::

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.649979] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    9.467550] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[ 1167.806072] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1267.083281] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -32
[ 1267.083489] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -32
[ 1277.114942] pl2303 ttyUSB0: error sending break = -32
```

Output of tail -f /var/log/syslog when plugging the cable:

```
Jun 12 16:48:25 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.727502] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.876263] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.876268] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.876272] usb 1-2: Product: USB 2.0 To COM Device
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.876276] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.876935] pl2303 1-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium kernel: [ 3678.877651] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 11 was not an MTP device
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium upowerd[1960]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
Jun 12 16:48:26 unobtainium upowerd[1960]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
Jun 12 16:48:28 unobtainium ModemManager[726]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2': not supported by any plugin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause: a defunct cable and possibly a counterfeit Prolific chip (pl2303). Using another cable solved everything including the impossibility to use the previous cable on a Windows 10 box with the latest drivers.